# PHP HTTP_USER_AGENT contains the word mobile

Tags: php, android

I need to check to see if the HTTP_USER_AGENT contains the word `Mobile` in it, but I am having an issue. Here is what I am trying:

```
$mobile = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Mobile");
```

Anyone have any ideas why this would not be returning true in my check?

```
if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry || $mobile == true) {
    if ($url == "/"){
      header('Location: http://www.google.com/');
      exit();
    }
}
```

I know this may not be perfect, but I am out of ideas to check between an `Android tablet` and an `Android phone`.

The User Agent string is = `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; SCH-I905 Build/IMM76D) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.114 Safari/537.36`

This leads me to believe that I am not doing anything wrong. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you may want to look at http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always worked 
Use it

[isMobileDevice](https://github.com/justindocanto/isMobileDevice)

```
<?php
    function isMobile() {
        return preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. This still seems to be returning mobile for my android tablet. I need it to go to desktop for my android tablet. Any ideas why?

Comment: because android tablet is mobile :)

there is no problem my iPad is always get mobile pages if i want desktop page clicking get desktop page 

I think there is no problem, it's normal

Comment: I dont think that is what i want though. Is there a way to not get the android tablet to return mobile?

Comment: I'm not very pro in Android, i never used before, i don't know. but i am sure you will find in google.

Comment: I used part of your answer to figure out the solution to my problem. I ended up removing android and just using the mobile tag. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Read the manual on [strpos](http://php.net/strpos)...

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string

This will return an integer (the position) or false if not found.

So you'll want to do:

`$mobile !== false`

Comment: Okay, I guess i turned myself around a little bit when asking that question, but in that specific `if statement` it seems to return true anyway for my tablet. Why is that if it isnt even int he UA string to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

PHP has the [getbrowser()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.get-browser.php) function, it may help you with parsing